Magnetic Flux in presence of variable magnetic field
Suppose we have a changing magnetic field parallel with the $z$ axis that follows the equation
$$\vec{B} = \frac{B_0}{z} \hat{u_z}$$
If we were to choose a spherical closed surface $\Sigma$ with radius $r$ and centered at a distance $d>>r$ from the origin of the $z$ axis, Gauss's law for magnetism states that the net magnetic flux through that closed surface equals zero.
$$\Phi(\vec{B}) = \oint_{\Sigma}^{}\vec{B} \cdot dA\hat{u_z}  = 0$$
However, when we calculate the flux, $z$ is smaller on the lower half on the sphere since it is closer to the origin than the other half and thus $\vec{B}$ is stronger on the closer half and weaker on the other. Wouldn't those contribution add up to a nonzero magnetic flux, even though the same number of field lines both enter and exit the spherical surface? Is this a violation of Gauss' theorem for magnetic fields?
Image for reference:


How would you come with such magnetic field? It seems to contradict the Gauss law of magnetism.

I assumed a parallel magnetic field based on what one may find along the axis of a solenoid coil

By symmetry, it would be simple to calculate the flux using a cube, since it could not depend on the shape of the surface. However, your field has a nonzero flux over a closed surface, which contradicts Gauss law and could not be regarded as a valid magnetic field.

The magnetic field of a solenoid coil is not like that.

I see what you mean. The magnetic field of a solenoid coil is not like that, since it tends to curve even if you get arbitrarily close to the axis of the solenoid, as seen in this image. link
Even then though, it does get weaker with distance, so in theory there would indeed be a difference in B between the two halves of the cube or sphere we consider (imagine the surface being along the axis and at a distance d from the solenoid)

You are correct that your magnetic field does not have zero flux through some closed surfaces.  In terms of the differential forms of Maxwell's equations, this can be seen as a failure of $\vec{B}$ to satisfy Gauss's law for magnetic fields:
$$
\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{B} = - \frac{B_0}{z^2} \neq 0.
$$
So this is not a valid field configuration for $\vec{B}$;  there is no way that a magnetic field can have this configuration in space.
This shouldn't be at all surprising, but I think the conceptual issue that's giving you problem is this:

even though the same number of field lines both enter and exit the spherical surface?

If you want to think of this in terms of field lines, note that the density of field lines corresponds to the magnitude of the magnetic field.  In particular, this means that the density of field lines must be greater on the lower half of the sphere.  And that in turn means that field lines must be entering the sphere and terminating inside it.  Magnetic field line can't do this, of course, which is another way of seeing why this is an invalid magnetic field.  But if you called this an electric field instead, it would be an indication that there would be some (negative) charge inside the sphere.
(IMO, the contortions that one has to go through to think about this in terms of field lines are an indication that field lines are not the best way to think about electric and magnetic fields.  They're a useful visualization tool, but what you should really try to do is develop intuition about how fields behave, not how field lines behave.)

Thank you for your reply, you really did shed light on some aspects of the subject that I didn't grasp quite firmly before. This question started from a thought experiment I imagined based on the behaviour of the magnetic field along the axis of a solenoid coil, but outside of the solenoid's length. There I assumed the field to be more or less parallel to the axis, but to get weaker with the distance from the solenoid (which i called z in my original question). Would such a configuration be possible and follow something akin to what I described in the question?

Badly hand drawn ms paint diagram for reference:  link

@user467048: The fact that the field lines are not parallel to the axis turns out to make a difference. To see this, imagine a tiny cylinder rather than a sphere.  The flux into the cylinder through the "near" end cap is greater than the flux out of the "far" end cap, because of the reasons you've outlined.  But because the B-field isn't parallel to the axis, there's also a small amount of flux out through the curved side wall of the cylinder. This small amount of outward flux exactly compensates for the difference in the fluxes between the end caps, and makes it so that the net flux is zero.
